# jQuery code works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have the following jQuery code that works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer. It doesn't work in Chrome and I can't figure out why.

I'm trying to change the `background-image` of an element with this code:

```
$(".category-nav").find("a").each(function(index){
    if($(this).css("background-color") === "transparent" && !$(this).parent().hasClass("level1"))
    {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(/images/gallery/images/arrow-cat-list-grey.png)");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we see your html for this?

Comment: You have a typo here >>  `("background-color") === "transparent"` ..remove one `=`

Comment: That's not a typo. Triple === is good javascript.

Comment: @user1042031 That isn't a typo, `===` means exact match, including type ([ref](http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=js+operators&parent=core+javascript))

Comment: Do a test to determine whether Chrome fails to recognise `"transparent"` or fails to write the new bg url. It must be one of the two.

Comment: can you please update the question with sample of your markup.
I'm about to make a sample based on your scenario to test the functionality for you. so plz provide some markup

Comment: @Lix specifying the arguments of the function will not change this. He is not using the index or element from the arguments so no worries there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome returns the background color as `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` for transparent ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yfjNQ/))

Try this code instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yfjNQ/1/)):

```
$(".category-nav").find("a").each(function(index){
    if ( /transparent|rgba\(0, 0, 0, 0\)/.test($(this).css("background-color") ) &&
          !$(this).parent().hasClass("level1") )
    {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(/images/gallery/images/arrow-cat-list-grey.png)");
    }

});
```

Comment: I actually just came a crossed this the other day myself for the first time writing a hex to rgb colour converter... Was this a new change for Chrome? Or maybe I just don't manipulate styles with JS too often.

Comment: just discovered this thing right now, and was about to post the solution as you did. you caught me  :).

Comment: @rlemon I think that only transparent does this. Maybe the easiest way to remember is to set the color of the Chrome developer tools to rgb. Press F12, click on elements and select any element, then in the styles accordion click on the gear to change the output - http://i50.tinypic.com/beypty.jpg

Comment: I can't remember exactly the case (likely on transparent or slightly trans elements..) but in my testing I did notice this. +1